# Microservices communication: HTTP vs RPC

Tags: http, microservices, communication, rpc

RPC standard was created keeping in mind distributed computed but in Today's Microservices world we hardly use RPC for communication between services rather HTTP is mostly used.

I want to understand the reason for the same.

I can think of limitations like Serialization(not fast enough), reliability of messages transmission, no multithreading, lack of asynchronous communication etc which RPC might have and might present some sort of bottleneck considering the scalability requirements of today.

but when I searched for these limitations on web, I got the impression that these might not be a huge problem today and some where there is a framework/lib which solves all or some of these limitations.

So, I wanted to understand what exactly is the reason for RPC not being very popular for microservices communication in spite they are older than HTTP.

Comment: gRPC is being sufficiently used for the inter-microservices communication, maybe mostly the browers ppl use and they way DNS and gateway setups are done , things are still stick to HTTP and gRPC operates under the hood of HTTP2, and it was a huge trouble that my group faced while integrating the other services running at HTTP with gRPC, it was really cumbersome to know what happens under the hood

Comment: @TusharMahajan Thanks for reply. In your setup, Do you think RPC communication is scaleable and also other than integrating HTTP and RPC, did you notice anyother operational bottleneck with RPC communication which might cause problem for an enterprise application which expects huge traffic.

Comment: I didn't feel any issues with scalability and for high traffic volumes it supports streams along with unary apis, hence no such issues. Only HTTP to HTTP/2 communication via reverse proxy layer was a headache for us

Comment: @TusharMahajan Any specific reason you choose RPC? I assume if you knew some of your components (may be 3rd party) are using HTTP, integration would be lot more easier if you would have chosen HTTP and one more thing, how are managing service discovery for newly added nodes?

Comment: just speed is one concern, HTTP2 based communication for internal microservices is much faster than HTTP1 and SSL protections kinda things come under the hood too.

Answer (score 0):

Any communication across the internet or across a complex network is going to run into all kinds of hangups if it forgoes using HTTP... HTTP coordinates the behavior of proxies, gateways, tunnels, defines errors & statuses... you're gona end up having to implement that yourself. For any communication between organizations you need a standard way of implementing that. You also run into compatibility issues between types and versions of OS's and languages. For internal systems people used interface description languages to mitigate the OS / language issue but this adds complexity and only works within an organization. Even if you were to use your own custom implementation.. it's alot of redundant work for not alot of payoff. But the idea of microservices is they should be reusable by a variety of systems, so this is not very compatible with the idea of microservices.

Now, you can add RPC on top of HTTP. This is used, though it raises a more general question about design. Prior to SOAs (service orientation architectures) there was a time people used distributed object architectures. Distributed objects used RMI (remote method invocation), just RPC for objects. There were a couple reasons this approach was abandoned for SOA and eventually REST -

A) it was difficult to support transactions with distributed objects because the objects needed to manage complex state but there was no defined way for interaction to take place. There was often tight coupling between the distributed objects. Among other things SOA decouples things, and this makes transactions easier.

B) Eventually there was a shift to REST, where services were stateless and all the logic / management of state was left to the client. This further reduces the complexity of the services and made them alot more orthogonal. But this is different from RPC where processing happens on the server, with REST it happens on the client.

C) again integration problems. This is mitigated by using HTTP, but not entirely as RPC requires the clients to implement the RPC interface which adds complexity.

D) the original idea of RPC is that the interface should be transparent to the programmer, but in a system that's geographically distributed that transparency is not possible to maintain due to network delays. So you're left with something that isn't such a giant improvement on sending a regular HTTP request.

So to answer the question... there just usually isn't much benefit to using RPC without HTTP except in very specific circumstances, like if you're designing middleware for a high performance cluster and you don't want the overhead of sending HTTP requests. But even then, it's a small amount of performance for a big investment, and it'd have to be a special use case because you'd typically just reuse existing middleware for that.